# Equal of .apply from Pandas to PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have the following dataframe on pyspark

```
+--------------------+-----+
|            activity| diff|
+--------------------+-----+
|      Ajustar nómina|33339|
|Generar archivo p...| 1383|
|Generar archivo p...|  269|
|Contabilizar Nomi...|  561|
```

and the following function I have made

```
def to_date(seconds=0):
'''
:param seconds:
:return:
'''
dat = ''
if seconds == 0:
    return '0 s'
if (seconds / 2678400) >= 1:
    month = round((seconds/2678400), 1)
    # seconds = (seconds - 2678400 * int(seconds / 2678400))
    if month > 1:
        return f'{month} months'
    else:
        return f'{month} month'
if (seconds / 86400) >= 1:
    day = round((seconds / 86400), 1)
    # seconds = (seconds - 86400 * int(seconds / 86400))
    if day > 1:
        return f'{day} days'
    else:
        return f'{day} day'
if (seconds / 3600) >= 1:
    hour = round((seconds / 3600), 1)
    # seconds = (seconds - 3600 * int(seconds / 3600))
    return f'{hour} hr'
if (seconds / 60) >= 1:
    minutes = (int(seconds / 60))
    return f'{minutes} min'
else:
    seconds = int(seconds)
    return f'{seconds} s'
return dat
```

I would like to know if there is an equal to `df.apply(to_date)` on PySpark, I would like to achieve applying the function `to_date` on each row of the PySpark Dataframe `df`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question I understood how to do it:

```
udf_to_date = F.udf(to_date, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("mean_2", udf_to_date("diff"))
```

If anyone knows a better solution I'm open to recieve them, Thank you!